# Clojure single function argument of large hash-map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap, argument-passing, destructuring

I'm trying to parse the result of an old API that returns CSV data (with no header). The `parse-response` function works great, but when I try to check with `verify-response` it fails with `ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentHashMap`. How can I pass the hash-map through a function that checks for a key field and creates an alternative error hash-map if it is invalid?

```
(def response-fields
  [:response_code :response_text
   :address :city :state :zip_code :country
   :phone :fax :email
   :first_name :last_name :company  
   :special_instructions :SpecialCode
   ])

(defn parse-response
  "One line CSV file"
  [response]
  (zipmap response-fields
    (first (csv/read-csv (:body response)))))

(defn verify-response
  "Get response if code is valid"
  [response-map]
  (cond (some? (:response_code response-map)) (response-map)
        :else
        {:response_code "911"
         :response_text "API Failure"}))
```

Comment: Looks like an errant set of parens around response-map.

Comment: @Alex, that should be made an answer and accepted so this question does not appear as "unanswered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an errant set of parentheses around `response-map` in the body of `verify-response`. `(response-map)` calls the map as a function with no arguments. Maps in Clojure implement the `IFn` interface; they can be called with 1 or 2 arguments to do a lookup on themselves, with an optional default value.

```
user=> ({:a 1} :a)
1
user=> ({:a 1} :b :foo)
:foo
user=> ({:a 1})
;; ArityException Wrong number of args (0) passed to: PersistentArrayMap
```